# Creación de formulario con distintos tipos de campos en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Me dispongo de realizar o crear un formulario de registro de usuario, pero este registro debe llevar varios campos los típicos de "Nombre", "Apellido", etc. Esto es para wordpress, y no consigo un plugin de formulario que tenga campos de tipo file, que le permitan subir archivos al usuario desde el formulario. Tengo el plugin User Registration, el cual me permite agregar los campos tipicos que ya mencione,  pero no incluye el campo  "file" para la carga de archivos. Qué extención gratuita, puedo utilizar para extender el plugin de User Registration? o de que manera se podría colocar un campo de subida de archivos que se pueda enviar en ese formulario. Ya he utilizado plugins com Form maker, o contact form, mailchimp. Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: ProfilePress te permite hacer esto, pero no es gratis, así que no creo que cuenta como respuesta a tu pregunta original. Pero tenlo en consideración por si no encuentras otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es una cuestión de conocimientos de HTML:

Mira
[esta información](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)